# Geting error in qemu "No such file or directory"

Tags: qemu

I want to install windows 10 64 bit but the my current verson of windows is 32 bit so it is unable to run the setup.exe file so booted into ubuntu 14.10 64 bit and installed qemu to use my current harddisk as virtual harddisk and the iso cdrom. This is the command I use

`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu qemu64 -vga std -cdrom file=~/WindowsTechnicalPreview-x64-EN-US.iso -boot d -drive /dev/sda1`

But this gives me error

`qemu-system-x86_64: -cdrom file=/home/ubuntu/WindowsTechnicalPreview-x64-EN-US.iso: could not open disk image file=/home/ubuntu/WindowsTechnicalPreview-x64-EN-US.iso: Could not open 'file=/home/ubuntu/WindowsTechnicalPreview-x64-EN-US.iso': No such file or directory`

But I have checked the file exists

Comment: No, the file `file=/home/ubuntu/WindowsTechnicalPreview-x64-EN-US.iso` doesn't exist. The file `/home/ubuntu/WindowsTechnicalPreview-x64-EN-US.iso` on the other hand probably exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-cdrom SOMEFILE` is a shortcut for `-drive index=2,media=cdrom,file=SOMEFILE`. Either use the verbose `-drive` option or the `-cdrom` shortcut, don't mix them up. You've told Qemu to open a file called `file=/home/ubuntu/WindowsTechnicalPreview-x64-EN-US.iso'`, and this file doesn't exist.